# ¿Cómo pasar los datos de una ventana a otra?

Tags: java

quiero pasar los datos introducidos de una ventana a otra a través de un textField, pero cuando lo paso el valor introducido esta vacio, si lo hago a través de un `String valor = "valor";` si me traspada dichos datos introducidos, pero si lo hago como he dicho `String valor = txtValor.getText();` la otra ventana me aparece en blanco.
Lo hago con

```
String valor() {
String valor = txtValor.getText();
return valor;
}
```

Porque??

Comment: Falta información en tu pregunta. Intuyo que estás usando Swing aunque me puedo estar equivocando. ¿Podrías por favor añadir más información así como tu código a la pregunta?

Comment: Si las ventanas están implementadas como objetos independientes, puedes coger el valor de la primera ventana y guardarlo en una constante estática y luego en la otra ventana recuperas ese valor.